# How can one open a specific tab in preferences via Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

So I know I can use `open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Keyboard.prefPane` to open Keyboard preferences. But how can I open the 'Shortcuts' tab specifically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use AppleScript from Terminal using osascript:

`osascript -e "tell application \"System Preferences\"" -e "set the current pane to pane id \"com.apple.preference.keyboard\"" -e "reveal anchor \"shortcutsTab\" of pane id \"com.apple.preference.keyboard\"" -e "activate"  -e "end tell"`

Replace ‘shortcutsTab’ with one of ‘keyboardTab’, ‘InputSources’, ‘shortcutsTab’, ‘Text’, ‘Dictation’ or ‘keyboardTab_ModifierKeys’ to change the tab it opens.

To find the list of available tabs in other preference panes, use
`osascript -e "tell application \"System Preferences\"" -e "set the current pane to pane id \"com.apple.preference.name\"" -e "get the name of every anchor of pane id \"com.apple.preference.name\"" -e "end tell"` where ‘name’ is the name of the preference pane.

---

To select a specific category of shortcut, you can use System Events to select a row from the left table.

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Preferences\"" \
          -e   "set the current pane to pane id \"com.apple.preference.keyboard\"" \
          -e   "reveal anchor \"shortcutsTab\" of pane id \"com.apple.preference.keyboard\"" \
          -e "end tell" \
          -e "tell application \"System Events\"" \
          -e   "tell application process \"System Preferences\"" \
          -e     "repeat while not (window 1 exists)" \
          -e     "end repeat" \
          -e     "tell window 1" \
          -e       "repeat while not (row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 exists)" \
          -e       "end repeat" \
          -e       "select row i of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1" \
          -e     "end tell" \
          -e   "end tell" \
          -e "end tell" \
          -e "tell application \"System Preferences\"" \
          -e   "activate" \
          -e "end tell"
```

‘i’ is the index (counting from 1) of the row in the left column of the preference pane tab. The new lines (using ‘\’ on the previous line) and white space outside of speech marks are just for formatting and can be omitted.

Be careful of the use of ‘repeat while not’ which waits for System Preferences to open to the necessary page, however this freezes the code until that point, and if System Preferences is preoccupied with something else such as logging in to iCloud which can't be interrupted, this will freeze until you manually quit.

Comment: Magical! is `get the name of every anchor of pane id "com.apple.preference.name` applescript as well?

Comment: Can I also open a specific item in the Shortcuts list, too? For example, 'Services'.

Comment: @Arthmost This would require some specific AppleScript for that preference pane. I'm using my phone atm but I can look into it.

Comment: Would be awesome, or just point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Arthmost I've added full code for getting the tab names and selecting the category of shortcut.

Comment: @Arthmost No problem! Accessibility Inspector app, part of Xcode from the Mac App Store shows the hierarchy which helps with things like ‘row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1’. System Events provides the ‘select’ action which can be found in System Events AppleScript dictionary (/Applications/Utilities/Script Editor.app, then select Open Dictionary from the File menu). The rest of it is [standard AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44359/discussion-between-arthmost-and-grgarside).

Answer (score 5):

Further to the answer from @grgarside (I don't have sufficient reputation to post this as a comment, sorry) not all IDs match the pattern `com.apple.preference.name` (which tripped me up for a while).

As of macOS Sierra (10.12.2) there are 19 preference pane IDs that match that pattern, 8 that match the pattern `com.apple.preferences.name` (note the s) and two outliers (`com.apple.prefs.backup` and `com.apple.Localization`).

To get the ID of the current pane (that you already have open in System Preferences) use:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Preferences\"" -e "get the ID of the current pane" -e "end tell"
```

To get every available ID use:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Preferences\"" -e "get the ID of every pane" -e "end tell"
```