# Using AppleScript to launch specific tabs in System Preferences panes

Tags: applescript, macos, system-settings

So I'm new to this and I might be overlooking something simple, but after failing to figure it out myself I attempted to follow the instructions from grgarside's solution to this question:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/250276/220050

What I am trying to do is open 'System Preferences > Keyboard > Dictation' (in Sierra, 10.12.2) using an AppleScript saved as an Application I've created via Automator. I've managed to open all of the other tabs within the 'Keyboard' pane (Keyboard, Text, Shortcuts, & Input Sources) using their anchors as part of an AppleScript but not 'Dictation', the 5th and final tab.

This is my current script, which opens 'System Preferences > Keyboard' but then halts with no error message. (I did note that it activates the Search field within the Keyboard pane though, which it does not do when scripted for the other 4 tabs)

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
reveal anchor "Dictation" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me under macOS Sierra:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        click radio button "Dictation" of tab group 1 of window "Keyboard" of application process "System Preferences"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Odd that you have to specify a click location for this tab just to get it to open but not for the other 4 tabs of the 'Keyboard' prefs pane, but I'll take it! I appreciate the help and i just wish I understood why it was necessary (for my own script problem-solving in the future). Thank you.

Comment: @NYKg, I can't tell you why `reveal anchor "Dictation" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"` doesn't work like with the other _anchors_ on that _pane_. It didn't work of me either and why I took an alternate route, which sometimes it what one has to do to get the job done. :)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do something like this for the Arrangement tab of the Display pane.  Unfortunately these names have a habit of changing from time to time, but for now under Big Sur, this works, exclusively using the System Preferences dictionary and no need for System Events:

```applescript
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    tell current pane to reveal anchor "Dictation"
end tell
```

If you need a different tab (not all of them are totally intuitively named), you can run this to get a list of all the tabs in the pane you're interested in.  e.g. for the Display pane:

```applescript
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    anchors of current pane
end tell
```

In the Result pane of the AppleScript Editor window, you'll see something like this:

> {anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays" of application "System Preferences", anchor "displaysNightShiftTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays" of application "System Preferences", anchor "displaysArrangementTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays" of application "System Preferences", anchor "displaysColorTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays" of application "System Preferences", anchor "displaysGeometryTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays" of application "System Preferences"}

So in my case, the anchor name for the Arrangement tab is `displaysArrangementTab`.