# Change mac dictation languge quickly

Tags: macos

Mac's dictation is a easy audio-to-text tool. however to change the language one has to go to system preferences every time. is there anyway to change between languages quickly(i.e by shortcut)? E.g if one can change dictation language by terminal, then alfred or shell script can change it with keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Have two users and just swap?

Comment: There is AppleScript provided in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/250276/350043 However, this opens preferences tab and will not change language.